# Entity Framework with ODAC

Tags: entity-framework, odac

I use EF with ODAC and it's Oracle.DataAccess and Oracle.Web.dll version numbers are 2.112.3.0, but on the server the version number is 2.112.1.0. My web application always is giving this error message:
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed. 
I think it is due to the difference of version numbers. I tried to copy these two dlls onto the server but it didn't solve the problem. How can I get through this problem? Must I reinstall some of the clients to fix this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: On the server where you see the exception - do you have any application that is using ODAC and working? This may as well be a problem with provider registration.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. No, it is an empty server. In the meantime there was a ora-1270 tns connect timeout error due to a firewall setting, but my colleagues solved it. Now I will try the new ODP.NET Managed Driver Beta.They say that there won't be any problems between the different versions.

Comment: Yeah, I would imagine this should work. If your app still does not work I would create a small app that is using just basic capabilities to make sure the provider works and is registered properly - this will be much easier to trouble shoot if things still don't work